# endfloat - order of appearance

Tags: table-of-contents, endfloat

I use the `endfloat` package to place tables at the end of the document. By default, the table list appears first and then the tables themselves. I would like to change the order so that we first have tables and then, at the very end, their list. Is it possible?

Here is an analogous example, but with figures.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[tablefirst,markers]{endfloat}

\begin{document}

\section{Example}

It is an example. 
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \rule{1cm}{1cm}
    \caption{Sample caption. Sample caption. Sample caption. Sample caption. Sample caption. Sample caption. Sample caption}
    \label{sample}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want the list of table before or after the figures?

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you want?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[tablesfirst,markers,nolists]{endfloat}
\AtBeginFigures{\clearpage\listoftables\clearpage\listoffigures\clearpage}

\begin{document}

\section{Example}

It is an example. 
\begin{figure}[htp]
    \centering
    \rule{1cm}{1cm}
    \caption{Sample caption. Sample caption. Sample caption. Sample caption. Sample caption. Sample caption. Sample caption}
    \label{sample}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[htp]
    \centering
    \rule{1cm}{1cm}
    \caption{Sample caption. Sample caption. Sample caption. Sample caption. Sample caption. Sample caption. Sample caption}
    \label{table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

---

Or is this more like it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[tablesfirst,markers,nolists]{endfloat}
\begin{document}

\section{Example}

It is an example. 
\begin{figure}[htp]
    \centering
    \rule{1cm}{1cm}
    \caption{Sample caption. Sample caption. Sample caption. Sample caption. Sample caption. Sample caption. Sample caption}
    \label{sample}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[htp]
    \centering
    \rule{1cm}{1cm}
    \caption{Sample caption. Sample caption. Sample caption. Sample caption. Sample caption. Sample caption. Sample caption}
    \label{table}
\end{table}

\clearpage
\processdelayedfloats
\listoftables\listoffigures

\end{document}
```